# Can we place code in memory section other than .text section?

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on a DSC by Texas Instrument in C language. I want to know whether i can place my code in predefined memory section other than .text section? if yes then how??

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: And what CPU are you using?

Comment: Normally you can, but it depends on the compiler and the CPU :-)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases yes, but the capability and the method will be linker and/or compiler specific.  Check the documentation for your particular tool-chain.  It may may be by compiler directive, or by explicit allocation in the linker script.

Answer (score 0):

In gcc you can select section function is placed into using section function attribute. Use is explained here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.

Together with linker script that places this section(s) at some appropriate region of memory, this works on "generic system".

Comment: But it's highly suspect that a gcc exists for a Texas DSC